# username and password checking from another file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication

I'm new to shell, I want to do the following task

A shell program which accepts username and password and checks the $username and $password with a line in another file (for authentication), I know how to get the username from user but how do I check against a line in another file. say I have a file called username (which has the username) and file called password (which has the password) how do I check $username with that line and $password with that line in the file

Comment: can you provide samples of your files please?

Comment: username.txt file has a single line "admin" and password.txt file has a single line "password" now how do I compare a string $username with the word in the file named username.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example script which prompts the user to enter a username and password and then compares them against the username and password taken from two files:

```
#!/bin/bash

# prompt the user to enter a username and password
read -p "Username: " inputUsername
read -s -p "Password: " inputPassword

# read the username and password from file
username=$(<username.txt)
password=$(<password.txt)

# compare
if [[ "$inputUsername" == "$username" && "$inputPassword" == "$password" ]]
then
    echo "valid username and password"
else
    echo "invalid username and password"
fi
```

Comment: @dogbane how does `username=$(<username.txt)` work ?

Comment: @Jidder `username=$(<username.txt)` in that dump the `username` from `username.txt` and saved it in `usename` variable.

Comment: @Jidder It is Command substitution. Look here it will clear your doubt  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities

Comment: So that command just dumps the entire contents of username.txt into username then ?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the perl cookbook:  (I guess it's no good though because the OP wanted bash)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# 

checkuser - demonstrates reading and checking a user's password

use Term::ReadKey;

print "Enter your password: ";
ReadMode 'noecho';
$password = ReadLine 0;
chomp $password;
ReadMode 'normal';

print "\n";

($username, $encrypted) = ( getpwuid $< )[0,1];

if (crypt($password, $encrypted) ne $encrypted) {
    die "You are not $username\n";
} else {
    print "Welcome, $username\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super basic and has no security but this should work for finding them in a file

**How i think it should be done(single file)**

```
echo 'Type username'
read username
echo 'Type Password'
read -s Password
awk /^$username.*$Password$/' {print "found"}' loginfile
```

**For the way OP has files set up**

```
echo 'Type username'
read username
echo 'Type Password'
read -s Password
UserCheck=$(awk /^$username$/' {print "1"}' Username.txt)
PassCheck=$(awk /^$Password$/' {print "1"}' Password.txt)

if [[ UserCheck -eq 1 && PassCheck -eq 1 ]]; then
     echo "Found"
else
     echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: You should match the start and end of the line in your `awk` pattern. Otherwise, if the user enters "pass" and the file has "password123" it will succeed.

Comment: the issue affects both

Comment: It will only match in the first if the line contains both username and password ? The second both must be found for it to succeed and say found ? I dont understand what you mean ?

Comment: @dogbane just realised what you meant. Ammending it now